# How to show result in HTML once promises are finished

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I want to show the result in HTML once the promises are finished. Currently, this is how I do it:

```
promoBuyNGetNData = [];//class variable

ngOnInit() {
      Promise.all(this.checkPromoBuyNGetN()).then(values => {
        this.promoBuyNGetNData = values;
      });
}

checkPromoBuyNGetN() {
   var result = [];
   for (let p of this.invoiceProduct) {
      result.push(this.promotionSvc.checkPromoBuyNGetN(this.username, p));
   }
   return result;
}
```

Then, in the HTML I write this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let p of promoBuyNGetNData">
        <td class="name">{{p.productGet}}</td>
        <td class="quantity">{{p.getN}}</td>
        <td class="price">Rp. {{p.price}},00</td>
</tr>
```

However, in the HTML it only shows an empty row. How can I fix this?

Comment: see {{promoBuyNGetNData}} values in html or console

Comment: @manikantgautam Thanks for your advice, there is a problem in the way I access the data in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @manikant comment, I should write it like this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let p of promoBuyNGetNData[0]">
        <td class="name">{{p.productGet}}</td>
        <td class="quantity">{{p.getN}}</td>
        <td class="price">Rp. {{p.price}},00</td>
        <td class="delete"><ion-icon *ngIf = "isShowInvoice === false" title="delete" name="trash"></ion-icon></td>
</tr>
```